# C# Can't Deserialize DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, deserialization, assembly-resolution, binary-deserialization

I have a client/server project and I'm trying to send via socket a DataTable(extracted from a TableAdapter) from server to client.
My server namespace is srvCentral and my client is appClient.
When I try to deserialize DataTable in client it throws me an Serialize Exception saying 
Unable to find assembly 'srvCentral, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
I've googled and tryed things like controlling the AssemblyResolve, that makes svchost hang and force me to close, and using a binder like this:

```
sealed class AllowAllAssemblyVersionsDeserializationBinder : SerializationBinder
{
    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        Type typeToDeserialize = null;

        String currentAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName;

        // In this case we are always using the current assembly
        assemblyName = currentAssembly;

        // Get the type using the typeName and assemblyName
        typeToDeserialize = Type.GetType(String.Format("{0}, {1}",
                                         typeName, assemblyName));

        return typeToDeserialize;
    }
}
```

And the exception stills there...
Wasn't it suppose to DataTable be Deserializable anywhere?
What am I doing wrong?

My Serialization code is:

```
public byte[] Serializar(Object item)
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    formatter.Serialize(ms, item);
    return ms.ToArray();
}

public Object Deserializar(byte[] buffer)
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer);

    formatter.AssemblyFormat = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple;

    formatter.Binder = new AllowAllAssemblyVersionsDeserializationBinder();

    Object a = formatter.Deserialize(ms);

    return a;
}

sealed class AllowAllAssemblyVersionsDeserializationBinder : SerializationBinder
{
    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        Type typeToDeserialize = null;

        String currentAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName;

        // In this case we are always using the current assembly
        assemblyName = currentAssembly;

        // Get the type using the typeName and assemblyName
        typeToDeserialize = Type.GetType(String.Format("{0}, {1}",
                                         typeName, assemblyName));

        return typeToDeserialize;
    }
}
```

**After some digging I've solve the problem with this;**

It isn't the better way to solve it but is a easy way to avoid the problem. For small things it's enough. Use this if you want to retrieve data from table for show content only.

```
namespace YourLibrary
{
[Serializable]
public class Tabela: ISerializable
{
    protected ArrayList colNames;
    protected ArrayList colTypes;
    protected ArrayList dataRows;

    public Tabela()
    {

    }

    public Tabela (DataTable dt)
    {
        colNames = new ArrayList();
        colTypes = new ArrayList();
        dataRows = new ArrayList();
        // Insert column information (names and types)
        foreach(DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
        {
            colNames.Add(col.ColumnName); 
            colTypes.Add(col.DataType.FullName);   
        }

        // Insert rows information
        foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            dataRows.Add(row.ItemArray);
    }

    public Tabela(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        colNames = (ArrayList)info.GetValue("colNames",typeof(ArrayList));
        colTypes = (ArrayList)info.GetValue("colTypes",typeof(ArrayList));
        dataRows = (ArrayList)info.GetValue("dataRows",typeof(ArrayList));

    }

    void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("colNames", colNames);
        info.AddValue("colTypes", colTypes);
        info.AddValue("dataRows", dataRows);
    }

    public DataTable GenerateDataTable()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        // Add columns
        for(int i=0; i<colNames.Count; i++)
        {
            DataColumn col = new DataColumn(colNames[i].ToString(), 
                Type.GetType(colTypes[i].ToString() ));     
            dt.Columns.Add(col);
        }

        // Add rows
        for(int i=0; i<dataRows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            row.ItemArray = (object[]) dataRows[i];
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        dt.AcceptChanges();
        return dt;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: @taras.roshko perhaps put a little more strongly than I usually suggest, but I don't disagree ;p

Answer (score 13):

> What am I doing wrong?

sigh; 1: using `DataTable`, and 2: using `BinaryFormatter`

let's take the latter first; `BinaryFormatter` is a type-centric serializer. Actually, you would probably have got away with this if you were just using `DataTable` rather than a *typed* `DataTable` subclass, but `BinaryFormtter` ultimately wants ***exactly*** the same types at each end. And you ***don't have that***. And even if you did, every time you version one end of the pipe, things could get a bit... dodgy (unless you invest extra care into this).

As a temporary fix, for this step, just use `DataTable` rather than the typed `DataTable` subclass, and it will probably work.

However, `DataTable` is *also* a pretty awkward thing to throw around - fairly clumsy and so general in purpose. If you ***need*** what it offers (in particular, dynamic columns) then .... *maybe at a push*, but in most cases using a basic POCO / DTO model would be far preferable. This is also easier to express on a client/server boundary, including most IPC tools. For example, the following POCO / DTO class (or a list of them) is very friendly:

```
public class Order {
    public int OrderID {get;set;}
    public string Reference {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

Personally, I strongly suggest that you look at switching to a simpler, class-based model, using a serializer that isn't fussy about particular types; `XmlSerializer` or `JavascriptSerializer` work well. If you need small / efficient data, then protobuf-net would be worth a look too. All of these work very well over sockets, too.

Comment: Datatables aren't a bad datastructure: they're very good in tabular data, and much faster with tabular data than a list of poco's, as their internal structures is a list of object[]. Everything has its purpose: if one wants tabular data, e.g. with optional views with filters on them, a datatable is a solid choice. Ignoring that is IMHO simply dumb. If the purpose of the data is a list of objects, a datatable is indeed a dumb choice (as it's about tabular data). However writing it off for all cases is IMHO shortsighted.

Comment: Great answer Marc, out of curiosity... could the version problem be overcome by exposing the object via an interface?

Comment: @DoctaJonez no; what matters is what the object ***is***, not what it looks like

Comment: @Frans I strongly refute ([with data](http://pastie.org/pastes/3960841/text)) that a `DataTable` is "much faster" - loading them takes the same time as POCO. Yes, `DataTable` has a lot of features (projections, filters, etc) - but so does (for example) LINQ-to-Objects (one-way, at least). Don't forget, the context here is data comms, not UI concerns. And sure, `DataTable` does have some uses... just, unless/until the dev can articulate the reasons for choosing `DataTable`, there may have been more more suitable (and simpler) alternatives.

Comment: Thank you all for the help.
Marc thanks by the explanation, I've already solved it creating a ghost table class and put it on the dll. I'm passing the data just to output it or execute a select and then output, so this method is enough I think.
I will see what is a POCO or DTO model anyway.

Comment: I wish SqlBulkCopy could use linq-to-objects.

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes it's possible to work around, but I wish it supported it out of the box.